# Rich text editor library for iOS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

Does somebody know a rich text editor (like `NSTextView` for Mac OS X) library for the iOS platform?

Comment: You know, one **amazing/bizarre** solution to this: it sounds crazy but, just bring up a UIWebView....  And then have your web-side colleagues make a perfectly sized "web page" for there, that is, simply, a CKEditor. Just click to http://ckeditor.com to see how perfectly, amazingly, after years of development, web rich-text-editing has become. It would be a staggering amount of work to equal that in a native app.

Comment: @JoeBlow This question is almost four years old. By now, the iOS SDK has gained lots of features which make creating a rich text editor fairly simple. Stuff like TextKit didn't exist back then.

Comment: Hey Ph!  Guten tag, I'm almost certain that **today 2014** there is no easy way to build a **WYSIWYG rich text editor**.  Sure, you would use TextKit but is like saying you'd use strings :-)  Amazingly there is no library for this.  (On the "under construction" one mentioned below, and the Omni project which is just a pile of sample code.)  The ONLY WAY I know to do it, is using the (bizarre/amazing) trick of using creditor inside a webView window (and then, somehow, coordinating with a server).  **IF YOU KNOW A SOLUTION, I'M WAITING TO SEND YOU MONEY!**

Comment: Note, TBC TextFields do today have (trivial) "rich" text editing built-in: hold down on a word and you can select bold, italic, underline.  {Note though that even that has no relation to creating marked up text, RTF, html whatever.}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Omni Group also released some code that could be the start of a rich-text editor.

http://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEditor/

Based on Core Text.

Comment: Is it possible to insert image in the TextEditor?

Answer (score 7):

I am following 3 rich text editors for iOS, available in GitHub. Below is the list:

1. [iOS-Rich-Text-Editor](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Rich-Text-Editor)
2. [RichEditorView](https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView)
3. [ZSSRichTextEditor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor)

ZSSRichTextEditor is best library among these.

Comment: Can we use ZSSRichTextEditor in swiftui also ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an attempt at a fully implemented one: http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtrichtexteditor/

Comment: This looks nice... unfortunate that it costs an outrageous $650 :/

Comment: Does this support rtf?

Comment: $650 vs $650,000 to build it yourself :)

Answer (score 4):

One doesn't exist, you'll have to craft one yourself. There are examples of using Core Text out there, if you just know where to look. For instance, the [I7CoreTextExample](http://github.com/jonasschnelli/I7CoreTextExample) is one such example.