# how to support richtext in iOS text fields

Tags: iphone, ios, editor, richtext

What is the best way to support richtext (bold, italics, font sizes, etc) in an iOS app?  I don't believe UITextView and UIWebView can do this.  What are most word processing apps using?

Comment: Do you want to hardcode richtext into a view? or give the user the ability to input it?

Comment: You might want to take at look at [`this SO question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542463/rich-text-editor-library-for-ios).

Comment: I want the user to be able to input/edit (like a word processor/text editor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One tool to do this is Core Text API

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) and the [documentation from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html).