# how to implement the edit like evernote -iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, editor, text-editor

I'd like to implement the editor like the evernote(iPhone edition): you can change the font and size and so on.

I'm totally blind about it and don't know how to search.

Could anyone help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several sources of help for you -

[Rich text editor library for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542463/rich-text-editor-library-for-ios)

[Open Source - Rich Text Editing](http://maniacdev.com/2011/07/open-source-rich-text-editing-view-using-core-text/)

[Rich Text Editing on iOS](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/)

Hope this helps. All of these (or most of these) use [CoreText](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I also found these documents, and it seems they're not so easy to understand. But it is in fact not so easy for rtf editor.

Comment: thats true. But its better than building something like this groundup. reuse code as much as possible...