# Cross-platform 'code edit' control (with syntax highlighting, etc)

Tags: editor, cross-platform, syntax-highlighting, rich-text-editor, scintilla

Currently, I have found Scintilla. It has a Cocoa port, but I am not sure how stable it is. And I think it is bloated. Any simple, cross-platform edit control with syntax highlighting (and possibly 'code folding')?

Note: No need for a GUI. Just the 'guts' are fine.

***Update:*** I was actually mistaken somewhat. I was confusing **'Rich Edit'** control with **'Code Editing'** control. **Scintilla is a 'Code Editing' control**, and that is what I am interested in. A control that has the best of both worlds would be icing on the cake.

Answer (score 2):

From your mention of Cocoa I suspect you want to develop for iOS.
If this is the case maybe this question can help you [Rich text editor library for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542463/rich-text-editor-library-for-ios)

Edit: http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?TextEditors there you find a lot of cocoa TextEditors (also for code, e.g. BBEdit or TextWrangler